# Why does using transform="translate(x, y)" make scrollbar unclickable?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, transformation, translate-animation

I've spent way too long trying to figure this out...I have an svg with some g elements and a foreign object. The issue is, when the g element gets translated, the scrollbar i have within the foreign object becomes unclickable. (I am using Chrome which is what I need to get working on...Firefox seems to be working fine though)

I have an example in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xd03mqyy/).

If you remove the transform="translate(...)" in the first g element, the scrollbar becomes clickable...but the position is a bit off. You would have to hover a few pixels on top of the scrollbar or up/down arrow to interact with it. Any idea why transform=translate() messing with the scrollbar and how to go about fixing this?

```css
.content {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:1.5em;
    overflow : auto;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1243" height="651">
    <g class="graph" transform="translate(200,20)scale(1)">
        <g class="output">
            <g class="nodes">
                <g class="node update" transform="translate(85.5,75.5)" style="opacity: 1; cursor: pointer;">
                    <g class="label" transform="translate(0,0)">
                        <g transform="translate(-75.5,-51.5)">
                            <foreignObject width="151" height="103">
                                <div class='content'>
                                    <p>a lot of text to enable overflow blah blah blah</p>
                                </div>
                            </foreignObject>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I would personally try and find an alternative to using foreignObject (overlays or something), if there's any complexity like transforms (and I'd probably avoid it even without). I tend to find it quite buggy, varies quite a lot across browsers and you can easily lose a bit of time on it.